# Exclude code coverage in assemblyinfo file

Tags: .net, unit-testing, code-coverage, assemblyinfo

I want to know how we can set the Exclude code coverage attribute for few files from assemblyinfo file? I am aware that we can set the attribute at class level but in my case I do not want to go to each of these classes and set the attribute.

I will like to set this attribute at a higher level or at a single place from where I can easily manage this. I believe we can do it in assemblyinfo file but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a .runsettings file to configure the code coverage as specified here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx

in that file use the "Source" element to exclude the source files you want to leave out.

```
        <Sources>
          <Exclude>
            <Source>.*\\Model\\.*</Source>
          </Exclude>
        </Sources>
```